# Add a <script> tag to the <head> section from a partial loaded via af:declarativeComponent in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have an ADF project (JDeveloper 11) with a few pages. All pages load a partial file that holds the top navigation bar, like this:

*mainFile.jspx*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">

  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
  <f:view>
    <af:document id="d1"">

      <af:declarativeComponent id="dc0" viewId="/partials/header-small.jspx" />
....
```

In the partial file I have this:

*header-small.jspx*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">

  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="some-stylesheet-file.css"/>

    <script src="javascripts/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/fonts.js"></script>

    <header class="top_header" role="presentation">
....
```

As it is now, the `link` and `script` tags are added in the `<body>` section, but I want them in the `<head>`. I couldn't find anywhere a proper way to do this. Is it even possible?

I can't implement templates at this point, because the project was created by someone else that is unavailable, and I'm only in charge of the front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the script and the link inside the `<head>` tag, I am afraid you will need to place your style sheet and javascript resources inside mainFile.jspx:

```
 <af:document>
   <af:resource type="javascript" source="../javascripts/modernizr.js">
   <af:resource type="javascript" source="../some-stylesheet-file.css">
  <af:form> 
   ...
  </af:form> 
</af:document>
```

So, you won't probably be able to get a high degree of encapsulation.
More details, here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/gotcha_when_using_javascript_in

Comment: This is a very backwards way for such an "elevated" language. I'll prefer the not-so-compliant links in body, than having to add them to each and every page.

Comment: Word of warning - it might not work on every scenario unless you place your javascript references in mainFile.jspx.  Depends on use case, but if  header-small.jspx gets loaded through an AJAX call, the references might not be processed. You should check, there is a good chance the application uses a single page (based on task flow with fragments). Then, you only need to add the links to one file. Yes, backwards - I know.

Comment: It's not single page, there are around 10 jspx pages, in which I've added the af:declarativeComponent tag to load some partials. They are processed in header-small.jspx, I was just hoping to move them in the <head>.